# StarUML show "in" in methods

Tags: uml, staruml

i use StarUML for 2 weeks now. I can't find the option for showing "in" in the methods parameters.
Is there any option?

I should look like this:
`-foo(in param1:String[0..3], in param2:int = 0): long`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, not knowing StarUML but the UML 2.5 spec says on p. 108

> `<direction> ::= ’in’ | ’out’ | ’inout’ (defaults to ’in’ if omitted).`

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded StarUML (4.0.0) and the direction of a parameter is not shown in a class diagram when its direction is *in*, contrarily to the directions *out* and *inout* whose are shown.

> Is there any option?

I didn't found an option to change that behavior and force to show the direction when it is *in*.

Example where the parameter *p_in* has he direction *in*, *p_out* the direction *out*, *p_inout* the direction *inout* and there is a parameter having the direction *return*, and I show the menu *Format* for the class :

[image]